# How to delete selected item of listbox after click a button?

Tags: c#, listboxitem

I tried  delete selected item of listbox after click a button.But I failed.

What is wrong in this code ?

Function for delete

```
public void RemoveFromList()
{
    int c = listNotMatchedItems.Items.Count - 1;
    for (int i = c; i >= 0; i++)
    {      
       listNotMatchedItems.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Click Button

```
private void AddToAnotherList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add to another list.some codes....
    RemoveFromList();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: InvalidArgument = '90 'value' index 'is not valid.

Comment: @user3107343: do you want to remove all items?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi No I want to delete only selected item after click button

Comment: @user3107343: then you can try my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** your function `RemoveFromList()` removes all items from the ListBox.

**Solution :** if you want to remove the selected Item only then use `ListBox1.SelectedIndex` to get the Selected Item index and pass it to the `ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt()` method.

Try This:

```
private void AddToAnotherList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Add to another list.some codes....
   listNotMatchedItems.Items.RemoveAt(listNotMatchedItems.SelectedIndex);
}
```

**EDIT :** in your `listNotMatchedItems_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler

Replace This:

```
string table = listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

With This:

```
private void listNotMatchedItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string table =String.Empty;
       if(listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItems.Count>0)   
       {  
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectDB1))
         {
            con.Open();


               using (SqlCommand comQuery = new SqlCommand(@" declare @vsSQL varchar(8000)
               declare @vsTableName varchar(50)
               select @vsTableName = @TT
               select @vsSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @vsTableName + char(10) + '(' + char(10)
               select @vsSQL = @vsSQL + ' ' + sc.Name + ' ' +
               st.Name +
               case when st.Name in ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar') then '(' + cast(sc.Length as varchar) + ') ' else ' ' end +
               case when sc.IsNullable = 1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end + ',' + char(10)
               from sysobjects so
               join syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
               join systypes st on st.xusertype = sc.xusertype
               where so.name = @vsTableName
               order by
               sc.ColID
               select substring(@vsSQL,1,len(@vsSQL) - 2) + char(10) + ')'", con))

           {

              comQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem);

                using (SqlDataReader readerQuery = comQuery.ExecuteReader())

                {

                    txtNotMachedQuery.Text = "";
                    int a = 0;

                    while (readerQuery.Read())
                    {
                        a++;
                      txtNotMachedQuery.Text = readerQuery[0].ToString() ;


                    }



                }


            }




            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM " + table, con))
            {



                using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
                {
                    listNotMachedFields.Items.Clear();
                    DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                    foreach (DataRow colRow in schemaTable.Rows)
                        listNotMachedFields.Items.Add(colRow.Field<String>("ColumnName"));



                   }

               }
             }
            }//if end
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Replace This:

```
comQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem);
```

With This:

```
comQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", listNotMatchedItems.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: It gives me error because I used some codes in private void listNotMatchedItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  }

Comment: @user3107343: which error you are getting, and what is code inside your listbox selectedindex changed event handler?

Comment: my codes in listNotMatchedItems_SelectedIndexChanged http://pastebin.com/VhMjqt5c I get error at line     "  string table = listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem.ToString();   "

Comment: Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thank you but   comQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem);   I get error :listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem is null

Comment: @user3107343: wrap up your event handler code inside the earlier if condition , check my edited answer

Comment: Sir I used your edited answer.But I get error :  comQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem);   ListNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem null error.

Comment: listNotMatchedItems.SelectedItem can not take any text !